# MFC: Which CFrameWnd function is called after CView::OnInitalUpdate() is called?

Tags: mfc

I have an MFC app that uses a `CSplitterWnd` to create multiple-pane views.  That process is done in the `CFrameWnd::OnCreateClient()` call.  After that, at some point, the various views have their `CView::OnInitialUpdate()` function called.  One of the views is a `CTreeView` and another a `CListView` with multiple columns that are setup within the `OnInitialUpdate()`.  I need to setup the default `CTreeView Item` which updates the `CListView` as well.  However, if I set the default within `OnInitialUpdate` the `CListView` has not yet setup the various columns.  Therefore it seems I need to set the default `CTreeView Item` after all that is done.  I presume I'd do this in some `CFrameWnd` callback.  My question is at what point do I do that?

TIA!

Comment: `OnInitialUpdate()` is called by framework just one time, during initialization.
Show your code, and highlight what exactly doesn't work for you.

Comment: The framework will call `OnInitialUpdate()` for all views and you have no control on the order these will be called (maybe the order the document templates or the views were created affects it, but it's not documented). An easy fix could be to post a custom message to the `CTreeView` after the `CListView` is setup, and setup the `CTreeView` in response to that message, instead of `OnInitialUpdate()`.

Comment: Well I moved it to `OnShowWindow()`. which gives me what I need for now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have dependencies between your views; that's not right.
The data should be stored in the document (even the current selection, if it supposed to be shared between views).
Than the view that is responsible for the change should call CDocument::UpdateAllViews(). As a result, all other views OnUpdate() will be called.

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cview-class?view=vs-2019

Comment: It's because the category window pane ends up sending a message of the selected tree item changed, so the list view ends up updating itself but too early (it hasn't created its columns yet).   So for now, I moved the selecting top / root tree item in `OnShowWindow()` for now.  Didn't know if there wasn't some type of `OnInitalUpdateComplete()` call back.